# Calculate ECI to ECEF Conversion Matrix in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-transformation, satellite

Currently, I'm following the [MODIS Level 1A Earth Location:
Algorithm Theoretical Basis Document](https://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/atbd/atbd_mod28_v3.pdf) to try to convert satellite viewing vectors from the ECI (J2000) to the ECR (e.g. WGS84) reference frame.

To do this conversion, it is necessary to first calculate the transformation matrix, which is defined as:

```
T = ABCD
```

Where **A** is the polar motion, **B** is the sidereal time, **C** is the astronomic nutation and **D** is the precession. Basically, I'm looking for a python function that takes **B** as an input and outputs **T**:

```
f(B) = T
```

However, I can't seem to find such a function online. Because of this, I'm tempted to write it myself, but would much rather prefer to use something that is tried and tested by others.

Edit:

Basically, I would like replicate the rECEFtoECI function described [here](https://juliaspace.github.io/SatelliteToolbox.jl/stable/man/transformations/ecef_eci/#ECI-to-ECEF) in Python.

Edit 2:

The [SOFA](https://www.iausofa.org/index.html) C/FORTRAN library has functions that accomplish the above described task (e.g. iauC2t06a). There are 2 projects that attempted to write Python wrappers for the functions: [pysofa](https://pypi.org/project/pysofa/) and [pysofa2](https://pypi.org/project/pysofa2/). However, pysofa does not work with Python3 and pysofa2 has not yet wrapped the functions for calculating ECI to ECEF transformation matrices, and it does not seem like there are plans in the near future to do so.

Comment: If possible, I'd recommend providing an example of what the data would look like. e.g. is each row a different set of values for A,B,C and D? If so, that will allow people to help you a little better. If that is the case, then you can calculate it by something like df["T"] = df["A"] * df["B"] * df["C" ] * df["D"] (this will multiply the columns ABCD together for each row and put the results in a new column. You probably don't need a specific package if there is a known formula since you can just 'recreate' the formula using the data you have

Comment: A known package, in this case, would be highly preferred because the quantities mentioned above (**A** **C** **D**) vary depending on which ECR coordinate system you which to transform to, and I would want to avoid maintaining such a library.

Comment: Never used it, but are you looking for something like [`pymap3d.eci.ecef2eci`](https://geospace-code.github.io/pymap3d/eci.html#pymap3d.eci.ecef2eci)?

Comment: I am indeed. I, however, would not like the coordinates but the respective 3x3 transformation matrix. The **A**, **C** and **D** values change with time, so it would be great if there was some library that pulled these off the web (from [this](https://www.iers.org/IERS/EN/DataProducts/data.html;jsessionid=E32945C0322689749675DAC125DEF875.live1) site for example) to form the above described function.